# Does the functional square root of the cosine admit a vector-based interpretation?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vectors, functional-equations

In linear algebra, the cosine of the angle between two vectors $a$ and $b$ is defined as $$\cos(a,b) = \frac{\langle a, b \rangle}{||a||\cdot||b||} .$$
The functional square root of the cosine has at various times been studied by mathematicians. It is the function $f(\cdot)$ such that $$f(f(x)) = \cos(x). $$ See for instance [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17605/how-to-solve-ffx-cosx) MO question. I wonder whether it is possible to have a vector-based interpretation of this functional square root of the cosine, similar to the cosine itself as defined above.

Comment: Sergei Ivanov's answer on that MO page says that there are many functional square roots of the cosine, none of them continuous. Which one did you have in mind?

Comment: @OscarCunningham the one based on the superfunction, as described by Anixx, including appropriate measures to counteract Runge's phenomenon.