Number in Base b as Dot Product
Question out of curiosity:
Any $k$ digit number $a_1 a_2 a_3 ... a_k$ written in base $b$ can be thought of as the dot product of a digits vector $a = \langle a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_k\rangle$ and a vector of powers of the base $b=\langle b^{k-1}, b^{k-2}, ..., b^1, b^0\rangle$
( For instance the number $365=3\cdot10^2+6\cdot10^1+5\cdot10^0$ ).
Given the cosine angle formula $$\frac{a \cdot b}{|a| |b|}= \cos(\theta)$$
is there a meaningful interpretation of the angle in the right hand side?

For small k, it is easy to draw. Like a cube grid of points sitting on some space https://www.desmos.com/3d/idxu82btpv and the base vector goes along a parametric curve.
Edit: Considering 365 vs 653, it seems like it has something to do with the "decreasingness" of digits given the sorted nature of b. Wondering what the pattern looks like.

Probably not. $|b|$ doesn't really have much meaning, even with a closed form, $$\sqrt{\frac{b^{2k}-1}{b^2-1}}$$

But $b$ can be taken to be constant, and then you could reasonably disregard the $|b|$ on the right-hand side and just ask about the relationship between $a$ and $\theta$, or between $\frac a{|a|}$ and $\theta$.  That might be interesting.

This is the first time I like a question, understand it, but am unable to answer it. Maybe we have a new angle to define from now

fwiw, for $k$-digit numbers when $k$ is large, $|a|^2$ will be distributed very much like a normal random variable with mean about $kb^2/3$ and variance about $4kb^4/45$. Since $a$ itself is distributed like a random variable uniformly distributed between $b^k$ and $b^{k+1}$, the quotient $a/|a|$ (which is $\cos\theta$ up to the constant $|b|$) will have some well-defined continuous limiting distribution (as $k\to\infty$) supported on $[0,1]$. (The distributions of $a$ and $|a|$ will be asymptotically independent because $a$ depends heavily on the first few digits while $|a|$ can ignore them.)

Reminds me a bit of this question I asked a while ago (also out of curiosity): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820898/does-the-functional-square-root-of-the-cosine-admit-a-vector-based-interpretatio

You can't really think of them as vectors because scalar multiplication and vector addition don't make any sense in this interpretation. Since it's not a vector space much of the geometry lacks meaning.

Partial answer
If I understand your definition correctly, here is a simple Python function to calculate $\theta$ (in radians):
import math

def vallev_angle(a, b):
    digits_vector = []
    while a > 0:
        digits_vector = [a % b] + digits_vector
        a //= b
    base_vector = [b ** k for k in reversed(range(len(digits_vector)))]
    dot_product = sum(x[0] * x[1] for x in zip(digits_vector, base_vector))
    norm_digits = math.sqrt(sum(x ** 2 for x in digits_vector))
    norm_base = math.sqrt(sum(x ** 2 for x in base_vector))
    return math.acos(dot_product / (norm_digits * norm_base))

So I calculated the angles with $b = 10$ for all positive integers between one and a million.
The 100 numbers with the highest angles (closest to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $90°$) are: 109999, 108999, 109899, 109989, 109998, 107999, 108899, 108989, 108998, 106999, 109799, 109979, 109997, 109889, 109898, 109988, 105999, 100999, 107899, 107989, 107998, 104999, 101999, 103999, 102999, 108799, 109699, 108979, 108997, 109969, 109996, 108889, 108898, 108988, 106899, 106989, 106998, 109789, 109798, 109879, 109897, 109978, 109987, 109888, 119999, 105899, 107799, 105989, 105998, 109599, 107979, 107997, 100899, 108699, 100989, 100998, 107889, 109959, 107898, 109995, 107988, 108969, 108996, 104899, 104989, 104998, 101899, 101989, 101998, 108789, 108798, 103899, 109689, 109698, 108879, 108897, 103989, 118999, 103998, 102899, 108978, 108987, 109869, 102989, 109896, 102998, 109968, 106799, 109986, 109499, 108888, 106979, 106997, 109779, 109797, 109977, 106889, 106898, 109949, 119899.
The single-digit numbers 1-9 all have an angle of zero.  Excluding those, the 100 numbers with the lowest angles are 91, 910, 9100, 91000, 910000, 81, 810, 8100, 81000, 810000, 71, 710, 7100, 71000, 710000, 61, 610, 6100, 61000, 610000, 51, 510, 5100, 51000, 510000, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 400, 500, 700, 800, 300, 600, 900, 5000, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 20000, 40000, 50000, 80000, 90000, 30000, 60000, 70000, 100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 600000, 700000, 800000, 900000, 911, 9110, 91100, 911000, 9101, 91010, 910100, 91001, 910010, 910001, 811, 8110, 81100, 811000, 92, 920, 9200, 92000, 920000, 8101, 81010, 810100, 81001, 810010, 810001, 711, 7110, 71100, 711000, 901.
So, it seems that high-angle numbers tend to be “bottom-heavy”, with high-value digits in the lower places, while low-angle numbers are “top-heavy”, with high-value digits in the upper places.  But I don't know any obvious geometric meaning for the angle.
